# Unable to serialize a KeyValuePair with YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, serialization, yamldotnet

I'm writing a simple class that serializes my `IConfiguration` interface which has the following method

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetAllProperties();
```

In my class I have a method

```
    public void WriteConfiguration(IConfiguration data, Stream stream)
    {
         new Serializer().Serialize(new StreamWriter(stream), data.GetAllProperties());
    }
```

But the `Serializer` doesn't write anything to the stream. Somewhere I read that `KeyValuePair` is not serializable, but this isn't the case anymore now (it was in .NET 2.0)

I tried first converting the `IEnumerable` to a `List` (using `.ToList()`), but nothing's changed. Then I tried creating a class to use instead of `KeyValuePair`:

```
    [Serializable]
    private class Pair<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public Pair() { }

        public Pair(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }

        public TKey Key { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }
    }
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work for me... I suspect it might be because you never dispose the StreamWriter, so it's never flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't dispose the `StreamWriter`, so it isn't flushed to the stream. Try putting it in a `using` block:

```
public void WriteConfiguration(IConfiguration data, Stream stream)
{
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
     {
         new Serializer().Serialize(writer, data.GetAllProperties());
     }
}
```

Note: by default, disposing the `StreamWriter` will also close the underlying stream. If you want to keep it open, use [the `StreamWriter` constructor overload that takes a `leaveOpen` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and pass true for this parameter.